# What to call a troll who persistently annoys others through jargon

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Not too long ago, I've encountered this god awful 'troll' on Discord who tends to provoke others without a break. The person would compose paragraphs of endless blasphemy purposely for the attention they wanted as well as to spam.

**Things they said:**

> "You are a preposterously maladjusted clod and a demented dull-witted abomination of humanity. You are trying ever so hard to sound clever dear, LOOL!"

Luckily, they were muted for their nonstop chatter. Why I was awaiting for this to nickname him.

Comment: Your quoted line doesn't sound jargony at all. Granted there's a few "_big words_" (lesser used) here and there, but they are not jargon. Most of them are not even obscure words.

Comment: Hello, I'd like to clarify on what is meant by the term 'Jargon' I used. The phrases in the quoted line would most likely not be understood from a majority view point and are geared toward Shakespearean terminology, which is why I classified it as "Jargon." I do understand it is not a literal form of it.

Comment: A troll is a troll. He is just **egregiously overblown horse's behind.** [haha] I'm sorry you had to go through that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Eddie Kal that your quote is not really an example of **jargon**, which means "uncommon words, or common words used with specific and uncommon meanings, used in a particular industry or profession." I do not think the words in the quote are "likely not to be understood from a majority view point," they are not difficult words, but they are over-the-top and not common in daily conversation.

The person you are talking about used [flowery language](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/209133/130147) and [five-dollar words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/255069/130147) ([see also](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45683/421933)). Such a person might be described as a [**tryhard**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tryhard#English)

> (*derogatory*) A person usually of little talent who tries hard to succeed, especially through imitation, usually to gain fame or popularity

or, if we are stereotyping and being uncharitable, a [**neckbeard**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neckbeard#English)

> (*slang*) A self-important, socially inept nerd.

"Neckbeards" are often perceived as being overly impressed with their own intelligence, as demonstrated by the ["You have to have a high IQ to understand *Rick and Morty*" copypasta](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/to-be-fair-you-have-to-have-a-very-high-iq-to-understand-rick-and-morty). The person you are quoting seems to fit this description, as they are trying to sound clever by using big words while at the same time mocking someone else for trying to sound clever.

Of course, because they are trolling, it is very possible that the person is *playing the character* of an unaware neckbeard and they do not actually think they are being impressive. But in the end, it makes little difference—they are being annoying and disruptive either way.

Answer (score 0):

The term "keyboard warrior" may be appropriate here:

> **keyboard warrior**
>
> a person who makes abusive or aggressive posts on the Internet, typically one who conceals their true identity.

Comment: I don't think this term fits what OP describes. The title is pretty clear and sufficient to identify a specific type of person/behavior. Keyboard warriors don't necessarily sound sophisticated as indicated in the title.

Answer (score 0):

One way to describe that is an **ad hominem** fallacy, literally, at attack “at the person” instead of addressing the real topic.  Less formally, it’s **name-calling**.

I wouldn’t call that “jargon.”  That usually means vocabulary that only a particular community of people will understand.